# Credhub Service Broker

Tags: cloud-foundry, pcf

Can we create a service broker for Pivotal's credhub? If yes then what will be the proceeding steps.
1) If credhub is deployed on bosh then how the broker will interact with it
2) If credhub is deployed on an EC2 in aws then how the broker will interact.
Any help is welcome.

Comment: are you trying to build a service broker that puts credentials in CredHub or consume a connect to a service that is storing creds in CredHub

Answer (score 1):

There is a CredHub instance that is used by BOSH to store all the credentials for the virtual machines that are part of PCF. This CredHub instance can not be used by applications running on PCF.

There is a separate CredHub instance that is deployed as part of the Pivotal Application Service formerly known as the Elastic Runtime. This CredHub can store application specific credentials. For example the credentials to access databases that would have been injected into VCAP_SERVICES.

I recommend you watch this video [CredHub and Secure Credential Management](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gQnM_PIMuE8) from SpringOne 2017.

Comment: thanks ams. Credhub stores service instances credentials securely. Does it also store application related credentials? Also apart from deploying it along with  the bosh director is there any other way to deploy it. I looked for in the PAS but didn't find it.

Comment: @Sneha http://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/2-0/credhub/ has the info you are looking for.